Android Emulator Cannot Access GPU from SSH Session
Attempting to optimize my development by running remote headless emulators.
I have a Windows machine with OpenSSH installed and can launch an emulator from the Command Prompt within an SSH session.  This works when I do not use -gpu host in the command, but fails when I do; the same command with -gpu host works fine from a Command Prompt within an RDP session.
Is there some setting somewhere, within the emulator or Windows itself, that will allow the GPU to be accessed from an SSH session?  Without leveraging the GPU, the emulator's performance is rather poor.
Here's the command and output from within an SSH session:
emulator @avd -no-boot-anim -no-audio -no-window -gpu host -feature -Vulkan

INFO    | Storing crashdata in: ...AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.18.db, detection is enabled for process: 5364
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.1.18.0 (build_id 11481568) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath ...AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-31\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: ...AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.18.db, detection is enabled for process: 2780
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
INFO    | Increasing RAM size to 2048MB
INFO    | IPv4 server found:
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 707c:28e3:9a01:0:707c:28e3:9a01:0    
...
WARNING | Your GPU drivers may have a bug. If you experience graphical issues, please consider switching to software rendering.
library_mode host gpu mode host
Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation supportandroid_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu infoI0307 16:37:27.742338   18236 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor di
sabled.
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString! arbFound 0 listarbNull/empty 1 0 extFound 0 extNull/empty 1 0 remote 0
OpenGL Core Profile not supported.
E0307 16:37:27.758973   18236 EmulationGl.cpp:94] Failed to find exactly 1 GLES 2.x config: found 0.
E0307 16:37:27.759338   18236 EmulationGl.cpp:300] Failed to validate creating GLES 2.x context.    
E0307 16:37:27.759912   18236 FrameBuffer.cpp:333] Failed to initialize GL emulation.
E0307 16:37:27.760548   18236 RendererImpl.cpp:141] Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

Thank you!
